# Trying to switch from Xunit.KRunner to xunit.runner.kre?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net, asp.net-core

Today after updating our projects it seems Xunit.KRunner is no longer available on NuGet.  We checked the Microsoft projects and it looks like they are using the xunit.runner.kre package.  When trying to install this the xunit.assert assemly is failing to download from Nuget.  Any suggestions to get this working?  I am guessing that the versions are messed up.

[image]

Here are my nuget package locations:
[image]

[image]

I'm also using the beta2 version of the kre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is/was an issue with the new xunit.runner.kre and VS CTP 5.  See below discussion:

https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

xunit.runner.xre is available only on [myget/vnext](https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/v2/api) feed. Include that in the Nuget.config that you should be able to restore the package

Comment: Thanks for responding Suhas.  I have added more details to my question above.  I already had that nuget feed included.

Answer (score 0):

By running on the beta2 kre you're then having mismatched dependencies. If you look at the versions of your xunit bits they're all beta3. I'd recommend upping your kre to beta3 to fix your issue (will affect which packages your app pulls in).

*Also as a side note* I'd recommend ensuring your nuget.org/api/v2/ feed is enabled (in the SS you posted it wasn't). There's currently an issue where it'll occasionally disable itself; has definitely made my life frustrating several times when things don't build :).

Comment: Thanks Taylor, but beta3 isn't available yet I don't believe.